# How to apply secondaryColor?

Tags: flutter

We can define `secondaryColor` in ThemeData like this:

```
theme: ThemeData(
          primaryColor: Colors.black,
          colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSwatch().copyWith(
            secondary: Colors.pinkAccent,
          ),
```

How to apply it in the following snippet?

```
ListTile(
    trailing: Icon(
        Icons.edit,
        color: ... , // secondary color here
    ),
```

Comment: You can try ```Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this

```
color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary
```